Multi-target CNOT gate using optical devices
I am trying to map a simple quantum circuit of two CNOT gates into optical circuits with beam splitters and phase shifters,.... specifically for GKP encoding.
I want to know how the arrangement of beam splitters would result in the outcome of this circuit if the input is a GKP qubit of
$$1/\sqrt{2} ({gkp_{000}} + {gkp_{111}}).$$

Consider to spell out acronyms.

Also you could show the quantum circuit. (How are the two gates, the three input- and output qubits  connected together?)

You cannot implement the gate with just linear-optical elements. You also need squeezing operations. You can find a decomposition of the CNOT gate for GKP states in this paper, specifically Equation 69.
